# Why is date getting formatted different than the method specified in javascript?

Tags: javascript, axios

I am trying to store the date of a note ( note taking app) in yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss format . But the axios post method is changing the format to ISO 8601 format .

```
class CreateBook extends Component {
  constructor() {
    let dt = new Date();
    let submit_date =dt.getFullYear()
    + '-' + (dt.getMonth()+1)
    + '-' + dt.getDate()
    + ' ' + dt.getHours()
    + ':' + dt.getMinutes()
    + ':' + dt.getSeconds();;
    super();
    this.state = {
      title: '',
      description:'',
      published_date:submit_date,
      publisher:''
    };
    console.log("here" + this.state.published_date)
  }
  
  onChange = e => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    

    const data = {
      title: this.state.title,
      description: this.state.description,
      // published_date: this.state.published_date,
      published_date:this.state.published_date,
      publisher: this.state.publisher
    };

    console.log("published date:" + data.published_date );

    axios
      .post('http://localhost:8082/api/books', data)
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({
          title: '',
          description:'',
          // published_date:'',
          published_date:this.state.published_date,
          publisher:''
        })
        this.props.history.push('/');
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log("Error in CreateBook!");
      })
  };
```

And the data in /localhost:8082/api/books is

> [{"_id":"5fd9d8a9d5fc172dec9870e3","title":"dgbd","description":"fbgdgb
> dg","published_date":"2020-12-16T09:51:27.000Z","publisher":"dgb","updated_date":"2020-12-16T09:51:37.146Z","__v":0}

why is this happening and any solution for it?

Comment: Is that published_date field an actual date type? If so, it might be automatically formatted at that point. I doubt Axios is doing it, seems like something the backend does.

Comment: i guess your're using mongoose on the backend. That is what is formatting it. consider changing the type of updated_date to string instead of date

Comment: @Tenotea I tried .toString() and console.log() shows it's a type string too but the time is still getting returned in ISO format.

Comment: Check this issue: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1548